# How To Build Query with QueryBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm currently trying to build a query with the Doctrine2 QueryBuilder. However, I am stuck when trying to do the following:

I have an entity called 'Customer'. This entity stands in a ManyToMany-Relation to 'User'. 'User' again stands in a ManyToMany-Relation to PhoneNumber.

So it's pretty much:

```
Customer <- @ManyToMany -> User <- @ManyToMany -> PhoneNumber
```

Now I am trying to select a customer based on a PhoneNumber. So right now I have the following:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('c')
    ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
    ->join('AppBundle:User', 'u')
    ->join('AppBundle:PhoneNumber', 'u');
```

Problem now is that I don't know on how to build the where-section of the query. Reason is that there can be several users and several phone numbers bound to the customer. Do you have an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Neither of these m:n relations seem right. One phone number can belong to multiple users? One user can be multiple customer and vice versa?

Comment: you set same alias for `User` & `PhoneNumber`, as @MarcellFulop say, you have invalid relation, how multi user can have same phone numder?

Comment: What is wrong about it? For example if there are two brothers registered that still live at home with their parents - then the phone number would obviously be the same. I noticed the alias-issue and fixed it but I still have the same issue.

Comment: @Chris what is your information for query?, have you `userId`, `phone number`, `customer id`, please more explain about parameters and that what will you?

Comment: I just have a phone number given. So now I should be able to search the phone number in the phone numbers table, find the corresponding user(s) and therefore the corresponding customers. And why keep people upvoting the statement that the 'm:n relations' are wrong? An explanation would be nice. In my opinion: One user can have two phone numbers (Phone number and fax number). One phone number (e.g. a land line number) can belong to several users (e.g. brothers living at home). One user can be responsible for several customers. And one customer may need more than one employee to help them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have entities with **mappedBy** / **InversedBy** you can do

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('c')
    ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.users', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.phoneNumbers', 'p')
    ->andWhere('p.number = :numberPhone')
    ->setParameter('numberPhone', $varPhoneNumber)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Using innerJoin() and 'MEMBER OF' fixed the problem. This way I can connect every entity with any other entity. E.g:

```
$qb = $this->getEntitiyManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('AppBundle:Customer', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:User', 'u', 'WITH', 'c.id MEMBER OF c.users')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:PhoneNumber', 'ph', 'WITH', 'ph.id MEMBER OF u.phoneNumbers')
    ->orWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->eq('ph.number', ':number')
    ))
    ->setParameter('number', $somePhoneNumber);
```